# How to implement comment functionality in Javascript using Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, svelte

I'm making an app that's similar to Instagram but I'm not sure how to create a comment functionality. The way my database is structured will be

**user** - email | uid | timestamp

**posts** - title | body | docId | comments | likes

**comments** - uid of the user that made the comment | the users comment | docId

**likes** - | uid of the user that liked the post | docId of post

I currently have the user function done and I can make a post and query it into my front end but I'm having difficulty with how to go about the comment section. I know that I need to be able to have the comment and like functionality after I query the data to my front end.

Am I going about this the right way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a little vague. When a user 'comments' on the post on front-end, simply create a new doc in `comments` collection.

Comment: Regarding schema, if you don't need to give the user functionality to see all his past likes/comments, you can have likes/comments as subcollection of post

Comment: I import my data from Firestore but how would I add the comment section to every post?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to be able to create a comment section for each post.  If that is indeed the case, can't you create a "foreign key" on each of the comments that links to the post. Then, when you load up the post, query for comments based on the post's ID. When you create a new comment, create the link to the post and you'll be ready to rock. Hope that helps. ;)

Comment: Yes, thank you for your help.

Comment: Does that solve your question?